# Why the output is “In foo, a = 7”?

Tags: c, assembly, thunk

```
void foo(int a)
{ printf ("In foo, a = %d\n", a); }

unsigned char code[9];
* ((DWORD *) &code[0]) = 0x042444FF; /* inc dword ptr [esp+4] */
              code[4]  = 0xe9;       /* JMP */
* ((DWORD *) &code[5]) = (DWORD) &foo - (DWORD) &code[0] - 9; 
void (*pf)(int/* a*/) = (void (*)(int)) &code[0];
pf (6);
```

Anyone knows where in the above code `6` is incremented by `1`?

Comment: The hex constants are machine code.

Answer (score 3):

`foo()`, as well as your thunk, uses the `__cdecl` calling conversion, which requires the caller to push parameters on the stack.  So when `pf(6)` is called, `6` gets pushed onto the stack via a `PUSH 6` instruction, and then the thunk is entered via a `CALL pf` instruction.  The memory that `6` occupies on the stack is located at `ESP+4` when the thunk is entered, ie 4 bytes from the current value of the stack pointer register `ESP`.  The first instruction of the thunk is to increment the value that is pointed to by `ESP+4`, thus the value '6' is incremented to '7'.  `foo()` is then entered by the thunk's `JMP foo` instruction.  `foo()` then sees its `a` parameter as `7` instead of the original `6` because the thunk modified `foo()`'s call stack.

Comment: Why is `6` located at `ESP+4`? And seems the thunk is calling `JMP (DWORD) &foo - (DWORD) &code[0] - 9` instead of `JMP foo`,right?

Comment: @COMer because that is how the C calling convention works.  Parameters are pushed on to the stack and then the return address.  When you first enter your code the sp is pointing at the return address.  As the stack grows downwards, the parameter is immediately above the return address in memory.  The return address is 4 bytes wide, hence the parameter is at `esp+4`.